# How to retrieve MAX and MIN value of an integer array in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, cl, rpg

In RPGLE (AS400) how to get the max and min value of an integer array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While sorting the array would work, it's not particularly efficient for typical min/max usage.  Sorting adds more overhead than a simple linear search and would really only be more effective if you wanted to get the values more than once on the sorted array and you don't ever need to add more unsorted data to that array.

I'd recommend just implementing it yourself with a simple for loop:

```
For Ix = 1 To %Elem(MyArray);
    If Array(Ix) > MyMax;
        MyMax = Array(Ix);
    EndIf;
    If Array(Ix) < MyMin;
        MyMin = Array(Ix);
    EndIf;
EndFor;
```

Depending on your usage scenarios, it could make sense to put that in a subprocedure or multiple subprocedures `Max`, `Min`, `MinMax`.

Comment: Thanks, this will work for me, sorting process will be a problem in my scenario... I need to keep the array unsorted. In this case i have to initialize Mymin with high value and Mymax with min value correct??

Comment: @KunalRoy Yes. That would be the best way to go about it I think.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `%min()` and `%max()` don't operate on arrays...

Best solution would be to sort the array in ascending sequence and then the min value would be the first entry and the max value the last.

If the array isn't completely full, make sure to keep track of how many elements you've actually used.  Then you could use the following:

```
sorta (a) %subarr(myarry:1:nbrEntries);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you add new elements to the array, you could keep track of whether the new value is less than the current minimum or greater than the current maximum. Then, the min and max would always be available. You could either keep track of the index of the minimum and maximum values, or keep track of the actual values.

Edit: As Charles suggested, I'm adding a link to the RFE to support something like %MAX and %MIN for arrays. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=116540

Answer (score 1):

There's an RFE to support something like %MAX and %MIN for arrays. It only has 15 votes so far ...
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=116540

Comment: I'd suggest adding this info to your other answer